# Detect image inside circle - HTML5 Canvas Game

Tags: html, canvas

I'm working on a HTML5 game using a canvas element.

[image]

I'm drawing a circle like this *(the user can move this circle around)*:

```
ctx.arc(chomperX,chomperY,chomperRadius,0,Math.PI*2);
```

I'm placing bomb images on in the canvas like this:

```
ctx.drawImage(bombImg,bombX,bombY,15,15);
```

The objective is for the user to move the "chomper" circle over the bomb image and eat it.  My questions is, how can I detect that the bomb is INSIDE the circle? I'm trying to do this by calculating the distance from the circle to the bomb image, but I'm getting mixed results.  Here's how I'm getting the distance.

```
bx = bombX - chomperX;
by = bombY - chomperY;
bombDistance = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(bx * bx + by * by))
if (bombDistance < bombRadius + chomperRadius) { console.log("THE BOMB IS IN THE CIRCLE!"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the bombRadius is less than chomperRadius,

```
bx = bombX - chomperX;
by = bombY - chomperY;
bombDistance = Math.sqrt(bx * bx + by * by);
if (bombDistance < chomperRadius - bombRadius) { console.log("THE BOMB IS IN THE CIRCLE!"); }
```

Comment: I tried your code, but not 100% accurate.  If the bomb is in the lower right of circle, it works, but it's in the top left or right of the circle, it doesn't work.

Make Sense?